# How to log 3rd party output in RapidMiner extension?

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging, rapidminer

I am trying to write a data source for RapidMiner that wraps an API connector library which my company develops for years.

The code is fine, but it fails to instantiate some classes. I am looking for the cause, but RapidMiner seems to suppress the 3rd party lib logging output.

Our library uses Log4J and for investigation I added a hack:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
// the appender writes the Log4J output to the JUL logger of RapidMiner
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new AppenderSkeleton() {

  @Override
  public boolean requiresLayout() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {}

  @Override
  protected void append(final LoggingEvent event) {
    getLogger().info(event.getRenderedMessage());
  }
});
```

As a result it writes at least the WARN messages to the RapidMiner log.

Then I found [this article](https://docs.rapidminer.com/developers/security/) stating that some operations are not permitted. That would be a possible source of my issues.

So my questions:

- How can I achieve that RapidMiner logs all the 3rd party lib output?
- Why does RapidMiner not log the security violations? That would help a lot for investigation.
- Is there any chance to bypass all the security restrictions of RapidMiner at least for development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would repost to the RapidMiner community (go to [Developer forum](https://community.rapidminer.com/t5/Developer-Forum/bd-p/BARDDBoard)) as the developers monitor that channel regularly.